# How to implement Comparator.compare(T o1, T o2) method

Tags: java, collections, comparator

`private static final String[] values = { FAULT, INVALID, QUERY, SKIP, SUCCESS, NO_ACTION }`

My use case required me to implement `Comparator.compare(T o1, T o2)` method in a way `public static <T> T min(Collection<? extends T> coll,Comparator<? super T> comp)` returns `FAULT`, when compare between `FAULT` and `INVALID`, returns `INVALID`, when compare between `INVALID` and `QUERY` and so on.

`String.compareTo()` wouldn’t work in this case because that would result into lexicographic ordering.

Comment: You can create a map for values where string's are key and index is value then you can compare index in compare function getting from map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple implementation here would be

```
Comparator<String> cmp = Comparator.comparingInt(Arrays.asList(values)::indexOf);
```

...which would find the string with the first appearance in the `values` array you have provided here.  (If any strings weren't in the array, those would be returned first, but it doesn't sound like that's the case.)

Comment: Or use an `enum` instead of `String` and get a natural order for free…